# Kotlin coroutines supervisorScope - how to make it wait until all launches complete

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I have some simple "hello world" code and i would like some help to know why the last statement printed is NOT this log statement:

```
Log.v("myFunc", "finished count")
```

My task is to create a `supervisorScope` that waits for all suspend functions to complete and then prints out a message. Here is the code:

```
 suspend fun fun1() {
    Log.v("myFunc", "1")
}

suspend fun fun2() {
    Log.v("myFunc", "2")
}

suspend fun fun3() {
    Log.v("myFunc", "3")
}

suspend fun fun4() {
    delay(3000L)
    Log.v("myFunc", "4")
}

suspend fun fun5() {
    Log.v("myFunc", "5")
}

suspend fun fun6() {
    Log.v("myFunc", "6")
}
```

later on somewhere else i do this:

```
 viewModelScope.launch(dispatchers.IO) {

        supervisorScope {
            launch { fun1() }
            launch { fun2() }
            launch { fun3() }
            launch { fun4() }
            launch { fun5() }
            launch { fun6() }
            Log.v("myFunc", "finished count")

        }
  }
```

and here is the log results:

```
2022-10-15 19:48:13.722 V/myFunc: 1

2022-10-15 19:48:13.722 V/myFunc: 3

2022-10-15 19:48:13.722 V/myFunc: finished count

2022-10-15 19:48:13.722 V/myFunc: 5

2022-10-15 19:48:13.722 V/myFunc: 6

2022-10-15 19:48:13.723 V/myFunc: 2

2022-10-15 19:48:16.724 V/myFunc: 4
```

I am very surprised the last result is not "finished count". What am I doing wrong ? Note the function 4 has a delay in it intentionally it should not matter as i still want all functions launched to finish before I print my final statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the log will be printed the last in that case. To achieve your goal the log should be moved out of the `supervisorScope`:

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

    supervisorScope {
        launch { fun1() }
        launch { fun2() }
        launch { fun3() }
        launch { fun4() }
        launch { fun5() }
        launch { fun6() }
    }

    Log.v("myFunc", "finished count")
}
```

In this case the coroutine will wait until `supervisorScope` has completed all of its jobs (`supervisorScope` returns as soon as the given block and all its child coroutines are completed), and then the log will be printed.